# Wkhtmltopdf - Link with different text as href link is not clickable in PDF itself

Tags: html, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

I am using version 0.12.4 of wkhtmltopdf.

For example when the html has a href of:

```html
<a href="https://google.com/">https://google.com/</a>
```

The link is clickable in the PDF, however when the text changes to anything different like:

```html
<a href="https://google.com/">Link to Google</a>
```

The link is still Blue, but not clickable anymore.

I use the following command to convert a HTML file dynamically:

```sh
wkhtmltopdf --javascript-delay 2000 --enable-local-file-access --load-error-handling ignore ${{parameters.inputFile}} ${{parameters.outputPath}}/${{parameters.outputFileName}}.pdf
```

I also looked at Github issues but it seems to somehow be related to the header or footer where links actually don't work. But I placed them in the body. So I expect it to work.

How can I fix this problem?

*EDIT 28-01-2022:*

We changed all URLs to full URLs in our PDF as we couldn't find another solution.